# Why IE9 (8) treat XDR differently with try/catch

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

So I want to do CORS in IE8,9, so I have to use XDomainRequest. So I created:

```
function post(url, data) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  try {
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.message.indexOf('Access is denied') > -1) {
      request = new XDomainRequest();
      request.open('POST', url);
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Which works fine. Then I come across [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/). It suggested this:

```
function post(url, data) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ('withCredentials' in request) {
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('here') // 'here' in IE8,9
    request = new XDomainRequest();
    request.open('POST', url);
  } else {
    throw new Error('XHR cannot handle CORS and XDR is not available');
  }
  request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Which should also be fine. But when I look at the headers of the network, the `try/catch` solution gives me:

[image]

while the `if ('withCredentials' in request)`:

[image]

They have different `Content-Type: text/plain`!! Someone know why?

Comment: There's an interesting comment in point 4 from this blog post by a former IE developer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx It says:

"Note: As of 2014, XDomainRequest doesn't appear to send any Content-Type header at all. It's not clear to me when this changed."

My totally speculative guess is that XDR is buggy, and that certain patterns of use cause it to set the header or not set it in an undocumented way.

Answer (score 0):

In the `else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== 'undefined')` code block the content type is not set, Since you're using IE8/9 this block will be executed.

Comment: It should also be not set for try catch, because I created a new request.

Comment: Are you sure there was an exception thrown?

Comment: Yep. we were doing a cors request anyway. XHR is not capable.

Comment: Try removing the `request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');` int he try catch and see what happens.

Comment: I found out what's wrong. IE treat different port as the same origin, so in my try/catch approach, XDR is not used at all. If you adjust your answer, I will mark it right. Thx!